# Calling a MySQL Stored Procedure in SQuirreL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, squirrel-sql

What is the correct syntax to call a MySQL stored procedure in SQuirreL?  Here's an example sproc?

```
foo(IN VARCHAR s, OUT VARCHAR a, OUT VARCHAR b, OUT VARCHAR c),
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in Squirrel 3.5.0:

```
call foo('parm', @a, @b, @c)
```